# Supervisor for User in laravel eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My current table is like following

User

- id
- name

Supervisor

- id
- supervisor_id
- user_id

However, I don't know how should I build for Eloquent Model.

I am not sure, should I write like that in `User` Model.

```
public function supervisors()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Supervisor', 'supervisor','supervisor_id');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\User', 'user','user_id');
}
```

Comment: Hmm, why use polymorphic relation? Ask yourself, can supervisor have multiple users? Can user have multiple supervisors? And post answers as comment please.

Comment: You can just have a `users` table which consists of `id`, `name` and `is_supervisor` fields. Is there any reason why you're going for a more complex design?

Comment: @Kyslik I'm working on leave system. One employee apply the leave. One or more supervisor can approve his leave. Actually, it's not supervisor. It's a permission who can approve his leave request.